# Is it possible to use ArcGIS to define a boundary around a self-constructed 3D feature?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, distance, 3d-model, sketchup

I am creating a 3D rendering of a future building and would like to know the distance from which this building would be visible from. Is it possible to use ArcGIS to define a boundary that delineates where you could see the building from? I plan on using SketchUp Pro 2016 to create the building and Arc to show the distance from which the building can be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is one of the options available under viewshed tools in the spatial analyst extension of ArcGIS.

https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/i-can-see-for-miles-and-miles/lessons/perform-a-viewshed-analysis/

Using GIS, viewsheds can be calculated to show areas where observed objects, **such as towers and turbines, can be seen, or, conversely,** to show areas that can be seen from specified objects, such as steeples or observation decks.

You will need a [DEM](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/GISDictionary/term/DEM) for your region.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like exactly what I'm looking for!